# Where and how to store locally-generated private keys on device?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, command-line-interface, cryptojs

I'm working on an end-to-end encryption system where users can send data to each other; the platform is accessible via web browser and CLI on the user-end. As part of the system, each user locally generates a private/public-key pair on their device (laptop); the private key is used to decrypt incoming data from others.

That said, I'm wondering what and where would be the general practice for storing private keys? — I've considered storing them in Keychain Access (for Mac OS) or in .netrc but then am unsure how to access them on the browser for decryption/signing when time comes for that.

Comment: The browser has local storage. As with any storage, it really depends upon what you're trying to keep it  secure from.

Comment: @jfriend00 I considered storing the keys in local storage but from my understanding its easily susceptible to XSS attacks — I also considered symmetrically encrypting the keys with a passphrase but then it would require the user to enter the passphrase repeatedly every time they needed the keys.

Comment: If you protect yourself correctly against xss attacks:

- validation of entries.
- csp.

It seems to me that you will have no risk, or very little risk in terms of security.

Comment: Are you trying to use these keys from browser Javascript?  Or from a native laptop app?  This determines what your options for storage are.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need users to be able to access the private keys both via browser and CLI.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know of any client-side storage mechanism that is available to both native app and browser Javascript.  Local storage is not available from outside the browser.  The OS-specific crypto storage mechanisms are for native apps.